# Retornar valor de función en servicio de angular

Tags: angular

Buen dia aprendo sobre Angular tengo un servicio que guarda datos en firestore y quiero que me retorne un valor dependiendo si guardo o no los datos hacia el componente, pero no entiendo buen como debo hacerlo esta es mi función en el servicio, digamos que quiero retornar al componente la variable VALOR

En mi componente llamo a la función digamos asi:

```
guadarDocumento(){
this.datosGuardados = this.docService.addDocumento(this.form.value, this.urlFinal)
```

}

En mi servicio esta declarada esta funcion, pero no logro hacer el retorno del valor :(, ¿alguien podra orientarme?

```
addDocumento(documento, urlDoc){
console.log('datos recibiso', documento, urlDoc);
let valor = false;
const docRuta= this.afs.collection(`documentos`);
const doc = {
  nombre : documento.nombre,
  codigo : documento.codigo,
  fechaAlta: new Date().getTime(),
  url: urlDoc
};
docRuta.add(doc).then(() => {
  console.log('registro guardado');
  valor = true;
})
.catch( (err) => {
  console.log('error al guadar', err);
  valor = false;
});
```

}

Comment: ¿Qué es exactamente lo que quieres retornar?

Comment: Puedes publicar todo el `docService`? Para entender un poco mejor tu codigo

Comment: Pues lo que quiero es que en esta linea en el componente que llama esa funcion en el servicio: guadarDocumento(){
this.datosGuardados = this.docService.addDocumento(this.form.value, this.urlFinal)

el servicio me regrese un Valor de verdadero o falso, dependiendo cuando haya guardado los datos en firestore o no ya que es una funcion asincrona en este caso, pero mas que eso es entender correctamente como hacer este paso de valores retornados de funciones desde el servicio, espero haberme explicado